# TypeError: Cannot read property 'isSupported' of undefined

Tags: angular, heroku, web, webdeploy

hi all i deploy in heroku mi web app in angular and i get this error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'isSupported' of undefined, but i watch that error is in tmp/build_d3e29b6b33fe23eae2f01eaec880901c/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/webpack-config path but node modules create in deploy.
i search but the only thing I found was: delete node_modules and run npm install . but in console heroku i dont make that.

any idea? please i dont know wath make. Thanks. My cli version and else:

```
<pre>"dependencies": {    
"@angular/animations": "4.4.6",
"@angular-devkit/core": "^0.5.6",
"@angular/cli": "^1.6.0",
"@angular/common": "4.4.6",
"@angular/compiler": "4.4.6",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "4.4.6",
"@angular/core": "4.4.6",
"@angular/forms": "4.4.6",
"@angular/http": "4.4.6",
"@angular/language-service": "4.4.6",
"@angular/platform-browser": "4.4.6",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.4.6",
"@angular/router": "4.4.6",
"@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-beta.9",
 "@ngtools/webpack": "1.2.4",
"@types/bootstrap": "^3.3.36",
"@types/jasmine": "2.5.45",
"@types/jquery": "^3.2.15",
"@types/node": "^6.0.90",
"angular2-modal": "^3.0.3",
"angularfire2": "^4.0.0-rc0",
"autoprefixer": "^6.5.3",
"bootstrap": "^3.3.6",
"codelyzer": "~3.0.1",
"core-js": "^2.4.1",
"css-loader": "^0.28.1",
"cssnano": "^3.10.0",
"enhanced-resolve": "^3.3.0",
"exports-loader": "^0.6.3",
"express": "^4.16.2",
"file-loader": "^0.10.0",
"firebase": "^4.0.0",
"istanbul-instrumenter-loader": "^2.0.0",
"jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
"jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
"jquery": "^1.12.4",
"json-loader": "^0.5.4",
"karma": "~1.7.0",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
"karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
"karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
"karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
"karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
"latest-version": "^3.1.0",
"less-loader": "^4.0.2",
"ng2-bootstrap-modal": "^1.0.1",
"ng2-tabs": "0.0.11",
"ng2-utils": "^0.6.1",
"ngx-bootstrap": "^2.0.0-rc.0",
"postcss-loader": "^1.3.3",
"postcss-url": "^5.1.2",
"protractor": "~5.1.2",
"raw-loader": "^0.5.1",
"resolve-url-loader": "^2.1.0",
"rxjs": "^5.1.0",
"sass-loader": "^6.0.3",
"script-loader": "^0.7.0",
"source-map-loader": "^0.2.0",
"style-loader": "^0.13.1",
"stylus-loader": "^3.0.1",
"ts-node": "~3.0.4",
"tslint": "~5.3.2",
"typescript": "~2.3.3",
"underscore": "^1.8.3",
"url-loader": "^0.5.7",
"webpack": "^3.1.0",
"webpack-dev-server": "~2.5.0",
"zone.js": "^0.8.4"
```

},

in package.json

If you need something more with pleasure

> Blockquote

Comment: Please work on formatting your question do it is readable. Additionally please supply the exact error message as it is so that others can use all of those details to help.

Comment: hi Daniel, my main error in console heroku is:   Cannot read property 'isSupported' of undefined
       TypeError: Cannot read property 'isSupported' of undefined
       at NgCliWebpackConfig.addTargetDefaults (/tmp/build_d3e29b6b33fe23eae2f01eaec880901c/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/webpack-config.js:91:51)
       at new NgCliWebpackConfig (/tmp/build_d3e29b6b33fe23eae2f01eaec880901c/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/webpack-config.js:16:29)

Comment: I got same error while `npm run serve:ssr` not sure which dependencies I need to import in under externalDependencies of angular.json